# How to add a column or remove a column from database using Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I Used migrations to add a column and remove a column like this

this is for adding column

```
rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string
```

this is for removing a column

```
rails generate migration RemovePartNumberFromProducts part_number:string
```

but I need to do `add column` and `remove column` using `Active Record` means how to change the existing model to add or remove columns

Comment: You have to do with the Migrations only.There is no another way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. SQL databases have rigid constraints. You can't add or delete columns. You could leave columns empty for a model instance, but note your database constraints must allow that.

If you really need to add/delete on the whim, consider using MongoDB instead.